# How to bind 'search' and 'search-repeat' to C-f in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

How can I to remap incremental search (<kbd>C-s</kbd>) to <kbd>C-f</kbd> in Emacs?

I try to do `(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'isearch-forward)` but the second <kbd>C-f</kbd> does not repeat the search and I need to use <kbd>C-s</kbd>.

I then tried `(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'isearch-repeat-forward)` but the first <kbd>C-f</kbd> didn't start the search.

And I even tried `(global-set-key (kbd "C-f C-f") 'isearch-repeat-forward)`, but this causes an error.

I want to use <kbd>C-f</kbd> for search and search-repeat commands, how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`(define-key isearch-mode-map "\C-f" 'isearch-repeat-forward)`

Comment: Worked!
`(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'isearch-forward)
(define-key isearch-mode-map "\C-f" 'isearch-repeat-forward)`
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

`isearch-repeat-forward` is defined in the `isearch-mode-map`

To resolve your problem do the following :

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'isearch-forward)

(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
 (define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-f") 'isearch-repeat-forward)
 )
)
```

EDIT: actually, you don't need to add a hook. The accepted answer by Ross Patterson is correct.

Comment: Worked with this solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why do this in the mode hook and not just change the mode map once, with a single `define-key` as @ross-patterson did in his answer?