# Emacs key binding for isearch-forward

Tags: emacs

I'm using Emacs v24.3 on Windows 7. I'm trying to learn how to remap key bindings.

I've created an .emacs file in my home directory and it contains one line:

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'isearch-forward)
```

I start up Emacs with runemacs.exe. I find a non-existant file, type some words (click at the start of the text) and type `C-F` to find. The `I-search:` prompt displays and I can incrementally search for text. So far so go.

The problem is, if the behavior is suppose be the same as the default `isearch-forward` keystroke, `C-s`, it isn't. When I type `C-f` a second time to search for the next occurance of the string, the only thing that happens is the `I-search` prompt appears in the minibuffer.

I'm not able to search for the next occurance of the string. Additionally, the `Del` key is suppose to repeate the search in the reverse direction. That does not happen for me when I search using `C-f` (though it does when I search using `C-s`.).

So this single key mapping seems to break two things. Am I mapping wrong? Or are these bugs? If I'm mapping wrong, how do I map `C-f` to the `isearch-forward` command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind 'search' and 'search-repeat' to C-f in Emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411920/how-to-bind-search-and-search-repeat-to-c-f-in-emacs)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Along with your one line, add:

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map "\C-f" 'isearch-repeat-forward)
```

The issue is that isearch has its own bindings that are active once you start an incremental search. Adding the expression above remaps the binding for `isearch-repeat-forward`.

If you're curious about these bindings, you can enter <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> while doing an incremental search to examine the full keymap.

Comment: Thank you. About the `DEL` key - the Emacs tutorial says `DEL` repeats the last search in reverse. I see that the `isearch-mode-map` defines `DEL` as the key to use to delete a character. Guess the tutorial is wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think the tutorial says that.  I think you are referring to section *SEARCHING* and this text:

```
>> Type C-s again, to search for the next occurrence of "cursor".
>> Now type `<DEL>` four times and see how the cursor moves.

If you are in the middle of an incremental search and type <DEL>, the
search "retreats" to an earlier location.  If you type <DEL> just
after you had typed C-s to advance to the next occurrence of a search
string, the <DEL> moves the cursor back to an earlier occurrence.  If
there are no earlier occurrences, the `<DEL>` erases the last character
in the search string.  For instance, suppose you have typed "c", to
search for the first occurrence of "c".  Now if you type "u", the
cursor will move to the first occurrence of "cu".  Now type <DEL>.
This erases the "u" from the search string, and the cursor moves back
to the first occurrence of "c".
```

A `<DEL>` does not search backward.  It removes a character from the search
string, and search moves to the previous hit (only) for the resulting string.
But the first `<DEL>` after `C-s` does not alter the search string.  It just
moves to the previous hit (only).

The tutorial text is not incorrect, though it might be a bit difficult to
read.  If you have a suggestion for improving it or just want to let Emacs Dev know that you find it unclear, please use `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But what you describe is not the behavior I get. The tutorial says >>If you type <DEL> just
after you had typed C-s to advance to the next occurrence of a search string, the <DEL> moves the cursor back to an earlier occurrence<<. In my case, on Win 7, it deletes a character in the text. But regardless, I can see the intent is for `C-r` to do the search in reverse and that in fact, works. The tutorial goes on to say that `DEL` will delete a character in the search string when there are no prior occurrences. But again, for me, the character is deleted from the text.